# does GrADS have a "astd" (similarly to aave) command I could use?

Tags: grads

I would like to have the spatial standard deviation for a variable (let's say temperature). in other words, does GrADS have a "astd" (similarly to aave) command I could use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no command like this in GRADS. But you can actually compute the standard deviation in two ways:

[1] Compute manually. For example:

```
*compute the mean
x1 = ave(ts1.1,t=1,t=120)
*compute stdev 
s1 = sqrt(ave(pow(ts1.1-x1,2),t=1,t=120)*(n1/(n1-1)))
```

n here is the number of samples.

[2] You can use the built in function 'stat' in GRADS.

You can use 'set stat on' or 'set gxout stat'

These commands will give you statics such as the following:

```
Data Type = grid
Dimensions = 0 1
I Dimension = 1 to 73 Linear 0 5
J Dimension = 1 to 46 Linear -90 4
Sizes = 73 46 3358
Undef value = -2.56e+33
Undef count = 1763  Valid count = 1595
Min, Max = 243.008 302.818
Cmin, cmax, cint = 245 300 5
Stats[sum,sumsqr,root(sumsqr),n]:     452778 1.29046e+08 11359.8 1595
Stats[(sum,sumsqr,root(sumsqr))/n]:     283.874 80906.7 284.441
Stats[(sum,sumsqr,root(sumsqr))/(n-1)]: 284.052 80957.4 284.53
Stats[(sigma,var)(n)]:     17.9565 322.437
Stats[(sigma,var)(n-1)]:   17.9622 322.64
Contouring: 245 to 300 interval 5
```

Sigma here is the standard deviation and Var is variance.

Is this what you are looking for?